# log4j configuration not writing application logs

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j2

I successfully configured log4j configuration by placing log4j.properties file in src/main/resources/log4j.properties
could not print application logs with below configuration.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, fileAppender

log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.com.myPackage=TRACE, fileAppender
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### File - fileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=./logs/myapp.log
log4j.appender.fileAppender.Append=false
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%r; %d; [%t]; %p; %c; %x; - %m%n
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        
        <log4j.version>2.13.2</log4j.version>
  </properties>
<dependencies>
<!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application class:

```
package com.myPackage.config
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevDataSourceConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DevDataSourceConfig.class);
    
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() { 
        logger.error("=================Dev environment, Entered into dataasource method===============");
        logger.debug("=================Dev environment, Entered into dataasource method===============");
        logger.info("=================Dev environment, Entered into dataasource method===============");
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName); 
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

configured log4j.logger.com.myPackage=TRACE, but from above logs, only error log is printing. Not sure, why. could someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your configuration syntax is for Log4j 1.x, not Log4j2.
2. The name of the configuration file is for Log4j 1.x not Log4j2.
3. You have all SLF4J calls routed to log4j 1.x.
4. You have Commons Logging routed to SLF4J.

Given all this, Log4j 2 is going to just use its default configuration, which is to log errors to the console. If you want to use Log4j 2 you should

1. Not exclude commons-logging from the Spring dependency.
2. Replace jcl-over-slf4j with log4j-jcl.
3. Replace slf4j-log4j12 with log4j-1.2-api.
4. Use a valid log4j 2.x configuration.